# moment .toJSON returns "0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaNZ"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and sometimes when calling:

```
myMomentVariable.toJSON()
```

I get back:

```
"0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaNZ"
```

instead of the ISO8601 string.

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid with my `myMomentVariable` somewhere in my code that causes this, but I can't find where... Any tips for what might cause this error?

Comment: Can we see that code ?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what `myMomentVariable` actually contains, it's created/populated, etc.

Comment: That happens when you're formatting invalid dates, whose internal representation is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Need code, but I guess myMomentVariable doesn't represent a valid date...

Answer (score -1):

check your variable before put it in moment function.
maybe you have to convert your date from string to date.
like let mydate = Date(myStringdate);